# making python 2.6 exception backward compatible

Tags: python, exception, syntax, python-2.x

I have the following python code:

```
 try:
      pr.update()
 except ConfigurationException as e:
      returnString=e.line+' '+e.errormsg
```

This works under python 2.6, but the "as e" syntax fails under previous versions. How can I resolved this? Or in other words, how do I catch user-defined exceptions (and use their instance variables) under python 2.6. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is backward compatible:

```
try:
    pr.update()
except ConfigurationException, e:
    returnString=e.line+' '+e.errormsg
```

Comment: The , syntax is certainly backward compatible, but it is not also _forward_ compatible.  This is invalid in Python 3 and raises a syntax error.  Yup, it's not a runtime error, but a compile time error that can't be caught.  See http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info and @Mario-Ruggier's answer below

Answer (score 12):

This is both backward AND forward compatible:

```
import sys
try:
    pr.update()
except (ConfigurationException,):
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    returnString = "%s %s" % (e.line, e.errormsg)
```

This gets rid of the ambiguity problem in python 2.5 and earlier, while still not losing any of the advantages of the python 2.6/3 variation i.e. can still unambiguously catch multiple exception types e.g. `except (ConfigurationException, AnotherExceptionType):` and, if per-type handling is needed, can still test for `exc_info()[0]==AnotherExceptionType`.

Answer (score 5):

Read this: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

and this: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes

Don't use `as`, use a `,`.

The `as` syntax is specifically NOT backwards compatible because the `,` syntax is ambiguous and must go away in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    pr.update()
except ConfigurationException, e:
    returnString = e.line + " " + e.errormsg
```